# Sorting data in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, data-munging

After data munging and using spread, I arrived at the following table:
[Complaint types and Boroughs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJXwl.png)

I would like to identify the top 4 issues in each Borough. Sort does not help since there are 4 Boroughs. Any thoughts on how to get?

Comment: So, I take a subset of each Borough and use order on it?

Comment: @Alex Tried order, testsort <- aggregatespread[order(-BRONX)]   Error: Object 'BRONX' not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subset the complaint type column with `order(column, decreasing=TRUE)[1:4]`. It will return the greatest four values in the vector. It is then easy to convert that to whatever form is needed; here a data frame makes sense:

```
lst <- lapply(df[-1], function(col) df[,'Complaint.Type'][order(col, decreasing=T)[1:4]])
as.data.frame(lst)
#     BRONX BROOKLYN MANHATTAN   QUEENS
#1 Facility Facility     Adopt Facility
#2    Abuse    Abuse  Advocate    Adopt
#3     Park      Air      Park     Park
#4 Advocate    Adopt     Abuse Advocate
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(Complaint.Type=c('Adopt', 'Advocate', 'Air', 'Abuse', 'Facility','Park'),
                 BRONX=c(0,5, 1, 33, 81, 7),
                 BROOKLYN=c(2,0,100,148,177, 1),
                 MANHATTAN=c(129,49,2,9,1,15),
                 QUEENS=c(50,3,0,3,2469,6))
```

Comment: worked like a charm! thank you! Could you help me understand what df[-1] and function(col) do?

Comment: `df[-1]` removes the first column. We don't want to include the complaint types in the count

Comment: `function(col) df[,'Complaint......[1:4]]` is called an anonymous function. I made up the name `col`, I could have used any string to define the variable. col just makes sense as a name because we are talking about columns. A full explanation of anonymous functions can be found at https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/the-art-of/9781593273842/ch07s13.html